# Compare a .txt and .csv file and need to replace with matching name in .csv file to .txt

Tags: python, shell, csv, awk

file1.txt

```
[fields:WinSpc:defect]
a=b
b=c
hello=hi

[fields:ROCKET PROJECT:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status

[fields:PROJECT_Nexus:defect]
title=summary
priority=Priority_hello
```

file2.csv

```
WinSpc,projects.winspc
ROCKET PROJECT,projects.rocket_project
PROJECT_Nexus,projects.project-nexus
```

I need to match these two files and desired output would be :

output.txt

```
[fields:winspc:defect]
a=b
b=c
hello=hi
[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status
[fields:project-nexus:defect]
title=summary
priority=Priority_hello
```

Just the name should be changed,

i have tried using

```
grep -Fwf, diff --breif,
```

and awk options but not getting desired output. Still learning these things. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to do? Look, your solution's just to call `.lower()` on the `file1.csv` file to get the result... But that's not what you want, right?

Comment: @math2001 just typo errors, so what i am looking for is. i need to compare file1.txt  with ile2.csv  and desire output should be output.txt as asked in question

only thing that i want to cocmpare and change is , if you see in file1.txt the name "WinSpc" should be changed to winspc..this  is the requirement

Comment: @SubratSahoo: It is still not clear to me, if you just want `WinSpc` to become `winspc` why do you need the other `.csv` file?

Comment: @SubratSahoo: Why is `ROCKET PROJECT` transformed to `rocket_project` and `PROJECT_Nexus` to `project-nexus`? why the difference? What is the idea behind

Comment: @Inian that's the desired output, and that's how the files are..i just need to replace ROCKET PROJECT in file1.txt to rocket_project in output.txt, that's why i compare. Similar for PROJECT_Nexus

Comment: The output file makes no sense. If it is about modifying the upper/lower case of the txt file then you don't need csv. If is is about replacing whatever follows `[fields:` in txt file with the entry in csv file then this line `[fields:winspc:defect]` of txt file should be converted to `[fields:projects.winspc:defect]`. Are you sure that desired output should not contain `projects.winspc` after `[fields:`?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou no the desired output should not contain [fields:projects.winspc:defect] , it should be [fields:winspc:defect]

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou any input guys

Comment: @SubratSahoo: To get any input, your input and output should make sense, You still have not replied to my earlier comment, Why is `ROCKET PROJECT` transformed to `rocket_project` and `PROJECT_Nexus` to `project-nexus`, Why does one have `_` and other have a `-`? Is it a typo or a requirment? if so how is the mapping done?

Comment: @Inian i think he tries to use the CSV file as a key + replacement. Key : `PROJECT_Nexus` (present also in txt file), replacement: `projects.project-nexus`. This is the only logical explanation i can think of.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: Makes sense now!

Comment: @Inian Yes.... it took one hour of discussion to SUPPOSE what OP wants( i am still not sure). Not well defined questions cause trouble.

Comment: @Inian sorry guys for my bad way of approach, i was unable to express. still thanks a ton for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more scalable `Awk` logic can be done something as below.

> Re-affirming the requirement for future readers, the `.csv` file has a `field,replacement-of-field`<sup>1</sup> pair stored in multiple lines. For all those `field` in `.csv` the corresponding entries in `.txt` file should be replaced with `replacement-of-field`

---

<sub>1. *replcement-of-field* actually involves only the part after the dot</sub>

The below command does the job as intended.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{split($2,list,"."); replacement[$1]=list[2]; next} \
   {for (i in replacement){ if (match($0,i)) {gsub(i,replacement[i],$0); break} }}1 ' \
      FS="," file2.csv file1.txt
```

produces an output as `OP` needed,

```
[fields:winspc:defect]
a=b
b=c
hello=hi
[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status
[fields:project-nexus:defect]
title=summary
priority=Priority_hello
```

Throwing in a bit of explanation,

1. `FNR==NR` logic ensures the command after it within `{}` is run first for the `.csv` file. Note that `.csv` file is read with field-separator `,`
2. `split($2,list,".");replacement[$1]=list[2]; next` ensures that the second column of the file is split by `.` and a hash-map is created with index set to value to be replaced and the value as actual value to be replaced. This is done for all the lines in the `.csv` file
3. Now on the `.txt` file, for each line is checked to see if the value to be replaced is present, if present it is replaced with the replacement value.

Comment: Did you try it ? Seems nice. One small remark. It seems by OPs comments that not the whole `replacement-of-field` is required by the csv file but only the last part of this replacement (affter the dot).

Comment: i also tried it, works fine! AWK is pretty nice tool.

Comment: @inian this works fine, sorry for my appraoch but i have some string names which are perfect and no need to replace. Like for example rocket_project is correct and no need to do anything...So when i tried this on multiple things this gives error as : (FILENAME=FieldMappingF.txt FNR=1) fatal: Invalid range end: /Sensor: SEN200/300 (was MIST) [AMS-LOCK]/

Comment: @SubratSahoo: Provide the input for which it wasn't working in question.

Comment: @Inian i have edited the question, so now you can see that there is "abl_tja1146" which doesn't need to be replaced and it occurs multiple times in file1.txt
So would your suggestion works here ?

Comment: @SubratSahoo: You are not allowed to change the input after this much time posting the question.

Comment: @SubratSahoo: This is a totally new requirement and the existing answer cannot be tweaked for this, revert the original question back and ask a new one, will quickly answer it

Comment: @Inian posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096234/compare-a-txt-and-csv-file-and-replace-the-occurences-with-reference-names

Comment: @SubratSahoo: Revert the old question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135100/discussion-between-subrat-sahoo-and-inian).

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's#,projects.#/#;s#.*#/fields/s/&/\;#' file2.csv | sed -f - file1.txt
```

How it works:

1. Transform *file2.csv* into `sed` **s***ubstitute* commands.  So the initial code
   `sed 's#,projects.#/#;s#.*#/fields/s/&/\;#' file2.csv`
   outputs:

   ```
   /fields/s/WinSpc/winspc/;
   /fields/s/ROCKET PROJECT/rocket_project/;
   /fields/s/PROJECT_Nexus/project-nexus/;
   ```
2. Run the resulting *substitute* commands on *file1.txt*.

   Output:

   ```
   [fields:winspc:defect]
   a=b
   b=c
   hello=hi
   [fields:rocket_project:ticket]
   description=Descrtiption
   status=status
   [fields:project-nexus:defect]
   title=summary
   priority=Priority_hello
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Taken into consideration your comments, this looks an exercise to replace values that follows `fields:` in txt file, using replacement values from another file where the "fields" value is a kind of key.

Have a look in this approach:

```
$ readarray -t a < <(grep -e "\[fields:" a.txt |cut -d: -f2)
$ for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};i++));do a[i]=s/${a[i]}/$(grep -e "${a[i]}" b.txt |cut -d, -f2 |cut -d. -f2)/g\;;done
$ sed -f <(echo "${a[@]}") a.txt
```

Output:

```
[fields:winspc:defect]
a=b
b=c
hello=hi
[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status
[fields:project-nexus:defect]
title=summary
priority=Priority_hello
```

Explanation:

```
# grep the first file a.txt for all the fields: and keep the second part, i.e WinScp . Store all those findings in an array
$ readarray -t a < <(grep -e "\[fields:" a.txt |cut -d: -f2)
$ declare -p a #print the array to see what is inside
#Bash Output: declare -a a=([0]="WinSpc" [1]="ROCKET PROJECT" [2]="PROJECT_Nexus")

# Iterate through the array and with the stored value (i.e WinSpc) grep the second file 
# (b.txt in my test) and get the second field after comma. Store changes in the same array.
$ for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};i++));do a[i]=s/${a[i]}/$(grep -e "${a[i]}" b.txt |cut -d, -f2 |cut -d. -f2)/g\;;done
$ declare -p a #print the array again. Now array looks like a sed pattern.
# Bash Output: declare -a a=([0]="s/WinSpc/winspc/g;" [1]="s/ROCKET PROJECT/rocket_project/g;" [2]="s/PROJECT_Nexus/project-nexus/g;")

# We can then apply all the sed patterns stored in array to replace values of text file (a.txt)
$ sed -f <(echo "${a[@]}") a.txt
```

Other solutions with AWK, etc may provide a more efficient code .

Comment: The solution should be scalable, designed to work if OP adds a new entry in file1 or file2, this design will not work if a new entry comes in. This needs a manual change to make it work!

Comment: @Inian What is the bug? I don't get your point. We extract `[fields:` from text file, we use value after `[fields:` of txt file to look up inside csv file and get the replacement part. Then we do the replacement with sed.... What am i missing?

Comment: I didn't go through the design fully, but hardcoding fields like `declare -a a=([0]="s/WinSpc/projects.winspc/g;" [1]="s/ROCKET PROJECT/projects.rocket_project/g;" [2]="s/PROJECT_Nexus/projects.project-nexus/g;")
` will limit the answer only the OP's input in question. Adding more such fields will not work is what I meant, not on the validity of the answer.

Comment: @Inian No, It is NOT hardcoding. It is just the output of `declare -p a` . I  requested to bash to tell me what array a holds. This is the default bash response when you raise a delcare -p command.

Comment: @Inian Try this to see what i'm saying : `a=( 1 2 3 );declare -p a`. You will see that bash will respond with all the details of array a (values, format, etc). Actually bash response will be `declare -a a=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")`

Comment: You did not understand what I meant, I am sorry, I meant having values like `"s/WinSpc/projects.winspc/g;"`, `"s/ROCKET PROJECT/projects.rocket_project/g;" ` which you added after manually parsing the file. All I am saying is, this might work for current input in question. if OP adds a future entries to file, your solution needs to be tweaked to make it work, in a way not scalable in future

Comment: @Inian actually all those values in the array are extracted by command `grep -e "\[fields:" a.txt |cut -d: -f2`. If the txt file has more `[fields:...]` will also be added to the array and the second grep will also search csv file for all entries present in array.  Also sed pattern is automatically generated using the format `s/grepped fields value from txt file/replacement valuer of csv file/g`

Comment: Refer my answer for a more scalable logic, see if it makes sense

Comment: @Inian i reformatted my answer  to be more focused and be able to understood that there is not hardcoding somewhere. Have a quick look.

Comment: It might just work, but am not a  fan of using `bash` for file parsing, Also it uses a bunch of utilities which causes too complexity. You don't want [Ed Morton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) looking at your answer though! :)

Comment: @inian Yes, i also prefer awk to be honest, but i have not study awk in depth. PS: I'm always a bit afraid of Ed sharp comments! :-)