# Compare a .txt and .csv file and replace the occurences with reference names

Tags: bash, csv, awk

File1.txt

```
[fields:WinSpc:defect]
a=b
hello=hi

[fields:ROCKET PROJECT:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status

[fields:abl_tja1146:autoticket]
description=description
status=status

[fields:abl_tja1146:risk]
description=description
assignedToUsername=assigned_to
```

file2.csv

```
WinSpc,projects.winspc
ROCKET PROJECT,projects.rocket_project
TJA1146,projects.abl_tja1146
```

Desired output is below :

output.txt or the original txt file can be appended (file1.txt)

```
[fields:winspc:defect]
a=b
hello=hi

[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status
```

As one of the string(abl_tja1146) is perfect no need to match them and should be ignored.

This is an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42084340/5291015) from an earlier question, but to handle the case when the fields should be ignored.

Comment: Why is `status=status` missing after `[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption` in expected output?

Comment: Having answered the other question, but this doesn't make sense. The new line just looks the others, there is no way to uniquely distinguish that

Comment: @Inian oops, missed that while typing, please ignore what is there under the first line of each snippet in file1.txt, those might change 
desired output should just replace the string in the first lines of each snippet i.e., (ex : [fields:WinSpc:defect] and [fields:ROCKET PROJECT:ticket])

Comment: Update the question, not in comments

Comment: @Inian i have updated

Comment: Is it safe to assume, there will be only two lines after field present between `[]`, e.g. `a=b
hello=hi` in file1

Comment: @Inian nope, it might have multiple lines

Comment: Let me know if the answer below solved your problem?

Comment: @Inian in the output i dont see a change in []
"WinScp" & "ROCKET PROJECT" is still the same it should have changed to "winscp" & "rocket_project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Awk` logic as below will do the job for you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{split($2,list,"."); replacement[$1]=list[2]; next} \
   $0 ~ /^\[/{split($0,newlist,":"); if(newlist[2] !~ /^[[:lower:]]/) \
      {gsub(newlist[2],replacement[newlist[2]],$0); print; \
          while(getline && $0 != ""){print} print ""} }' FS="," file2.txt file1.txt
```

produces an output as needed.

```
[fields:winspc:defect]
a=b
hello=hi

[fields:rocket_project:ticket]
description=Descrtiption
status=status
```

A hash-map of the value to be replaced and the actual value is created from `file2`, then on `file1`, a `regex` match is performed on lines starting with `[` and the second field is checked for string is perfect (lowercase in your example) if so that and the subsequent lines are discarded, else they are printed as they appear.